# How to use classic Django app with Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to use Django REST framework for my new project but I am not sure if I can do it efficiently. I would like to be able to integrate easily classical Django app in my API. However I don't know how I can proceed to make them respect the REST framework philosophy. Will I have to rewrite all the views or is there a more suitable solution?

Comment: Think of DRF as a machine-friendly alternative to your app's current `views.py` and templates. Views, roughly speaking, take models and render them to HTML. DRF takes models and renders them to JSON, XML, and other machine-friendly formats. DRF doesn't replace your regular views.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ If you're about to use REST API, then yes, you might want to get rid of your views, or at least redesign them, but it depends on how they look like. Without posting code snippets it's too broad to answer

Comment: Use `tastypie` if you want to keep your views traditional.

Comment: @xyres tastypie is equivalent to DRF, and offers no real advantage, especially as it isn't supported much any more.

Comment: @wobbily_col They are equivalent but the workflow is very different. If you're using DRF, you'll have to write your views the *DRF-way* whereas with tastypie, you can write your views however you want.

Comment: Waht's the "DRF way" compared to "however you want"? I don't see any restrictions on the way to write DRF views. The DRF class based views are equivalent to Django's generic views, and there are functional views as well.

Answer (score 2):

"Normal" Django views (usually) return HTML pages.

Django-Rest-Framework views (usually) return JSON.

I am assuming you are looking for something more like a Single page application.

In this case you will have a main view that will be the bulk of the HTML page. This will be served from  "standard" Django view returning HTML (which will likely include a fair bit of JavaScript).

Once the page is loaded the JavaScript code will makes requests to the DRF views. So when you interact with the page, JavaScript will request Json, and update (not reload) the page based on the contents of the JSON.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah I am looking for a single page app. I get the point with Javascript and Json. But my question still hold (sorry if it was not clear) : I would like to use django-messages (https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/tree/master/django_messages) in my API. This app was not designed for DRF as it provides classical views and template tags. Will I have to recode all the views into DRF views to provide Json to my app ?

Comment: Its difficult to say without knowing more detail about what you want to achieve (but I doubt you would need to rewrite everything).  You seem to be treating it as a one or the other situation, when you can easily server both normal HTML views as well as DRF json from the same application.

Comment: Obviously template tags won't be any use in json. But I imagine they make sense for the HTML part of the page that contains the JavaScript.